# Master volume missing on 16.04 upgrade

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I just upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 and I am having issues with sound. First, every time I log in my headphones are on mute so I have to manually unmute them from alsamixer. Also my master volume control which used to be under the sound icon in the top right is no longer there and can only be changed via alsamixer. Also there is nothing under 'output' in sound settings. I don't know if this has any repercussions on anything, but i'm sure there used to be a few things under there...

Anyone know any fixes for these?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To change master volume you must click on the sound icon in the top right. The reason why nothing appears in the output section could be a defect in the speakers, the motherboard, or Ubuntu itself.

Comment: I just said, the master volume is not appearing under the sound icon. And it can't be the speakers as they are all working - it's just that they don't show in the output, but they did before the upgrade to 16.04.